# Install UBUNTU 14 alongside Windows 8.1 (crack) on laptop (DOS pre-installed) now

Tags: 14.04

*Hey. I've spent around two days searching for the perfect forum for Ubuntu,but none found except this. I have a **Lenovo IdeaPad S510p which came with DOS pre-installed. I got Windows 8.1 (cracked one)** installed in hope's that C/C++/Java compiler's would easily work on them without any additional fuss, but that took me another two days and no luck. So decided to install Ubuntu. **My OS doesn't have UEFI, it still has BIOS.** I've got a bootable Pen drive and also changed the boot order to USB Drive. What i need to know now is what is the process like turning off the secure boot and all. I have no idea on how to do it. Thanks. :-)*

**P.S : All in all i need Eclipse and Geany for my programming and ill also be installing Kali in the future for my Cyber-Security classes and try it at my home network. :-)**

Answer (score 0):

If your laptop runs dos you either have a classic bios or csm enabled in your uefi firmware. So you should not have problems with secure boot.
Can you boot linux from your cd / dvd / usb?
You should be able to install it then.

Comment: No. My USB is bootable but i cant read it.